# Angular 7 - Having two formControls of different formGroups with same formControlName?

Tags: angular, angular7

Is it valid to have two FormControls with same formControlName but they're part fo different formGroups within the same form ?

Comment: Could you please explain me this part of question: '..but they're part of different formGroups within the same form ?'

Comment: I realised my mistake after posting question, being part of different formgroups mean they're in different forms ofc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is valid because you separate them by the `formGroup` attribute.

These are two `formGroup`s with same `formControlName`

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <input formControlName="name" type="text">
  <input formControlName="password" type="password">
</form>

<form [formGroup]="signForm">
  <input formControlName="name" type="text">
  <input formControlName="password" type="password">
</form>
```

Also if you take a look into the TypeScript syntax you can see that every `FormGroup` is object.

```
this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(),
  password: new FormControl()
});
this.signForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(),
  password: new FormControl()
});
```